# Could I get the name of current reference within Java?

Tags: java, reference

```
public class RefName { 
  void outRefName() {
    System.out.println("the current reference name is" + xxx);
  };
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
  RefName rf1 = new RefName();
  rf1.outRefName();   // should be rf1
  RefName rf2 = new RefName();
  rf2.outRefName();   // should be rf2
};
```

As the code above shows,could I make this happen within Java?

thanks.

Comment: why do you need this? What about: System.out.println(rf1.toString());

Comment: sometimes I would need to print the reference name to distinguish objects.It seems works well.Why would it happen?Is the later hex the heap address of the object?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rf1` is just the name of the variable, so even if you could get this working, it would not be a method of the class - after all, you could have:

```
RefName rf1 = new RefName();
RefName rf2 = rf1;
```

**this is the same instance**; what should `rf1.outRefName()` produce? No, I don't think you can do this. In C# there are some hacky ways of doing it (involving captured variables and either reflection or expression-tree inspection), but again - you are getting the *variable* name - nothing to do with the object. The better approach here may be to give your class a `Name` member and initialize the name in the constructor:

```
RefName rf1 = new RefName("myname");
```

Here, the name of the **object** is "myname". Not `rf1`, which is the name of the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done. What would the following print?

```
RefName a = new RefName(), b;
(b = a).outRefName();
```

Answer (score 2):

If this information is valueable, you need to pass this information in **yourself**.

```
public class RefName {

    private String name;

    public RefName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String outRefName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

-

```
RefName rf1 = new RefName("rf1");
rf1.outRefName();
```

Answer (score 2):

By using Reflection you can find which fields of an Object contain a given instance. This only works for fields, not for variables. Here an incomplete sample:

```
public class BackRef {

    private class RefName {

        // finds first field containing this object
        public String outRefName() {
            Field[] fields = BackRef.class.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if (getClass().isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        if (field.get(BackRef.this) == this)
                            return field.getName();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    private RefName ref1;
    private RefName ref2;

    BackRef() {
        ref1 = new RefName();
        ref2 = new RefName();

        System.out.println(ref1.outRefName());
        System.out.println(ref2.outRefName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BackRef();
    }
}
```

It's kind of a (big) hack, but I used it once to display in which field a clicked GUI component was saved...

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that we are coleagues and when I mention you to the members of my family we use some kind of nickname. Let's say 'The other day my *tall* colleagu said this'. There's no way for you to know how we do call you. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in Java. I guess you can clearly see why here:

```
(new RefName()).outRefName()
```

The "reference" never even got a name.